# Decipher handwriting

Tags: handwriting

This is from an old testament, written in 1945. I can read almost all of it, but struggle with the first sentence. Can you help?

[image: ri]

> Mein letzter Wille! In … als (?) schwerer (?) … für das deutsche Volk bestimme ich für den Fall meines Ablebens:

Many thanks in advance. (No translations required, I'm fluent in German.)

Comment: @userunknown What about this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It think it's

> In *schicksalsschwerer Stunde* für das deutsche ...

Comment: Of course it is. Duh! (And thank you.)